# Android Studio Cannot Resolve Any Symbols

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio suddenly lost the ability to resolve any symbols across all of my projects, suggesting there's an issue with Android studio itself.

[Android Studio](https://photos-4.dropbox.com/t/2/AAATHUeU-yHnRXjsTv83xZs12M53y7FuzHREpgZSasIx-w/12/483103303/png/32x32/1/_/1/2/Screenshot%202017-08-25%2017.10.54.png/EPSxs_UDGLwFIAcoBw/esPebpn3Gk9rFzPM1Z8GomQrMeSx8tIjmjzEjZzxp3E?size=2048x1536&size_mode=3)

Reinstalling Android Studio doesn't seem to solve the issue. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: That photo isn't publicly available

Comment: Can't resolve what symbols? Java or only Android? Is the JDK and SDK correctly installed? Did you upgrade those recently? Java upgrades automatically sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try *clean* project in the *build* menu.